# Background job with a thread/process?

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee

Technology used: EJB 3.1, Java EE 6, GlassFish 3.1.

I need to implement a background job that is execute every 2 minutes to check the status of a list of servers. I already implemented a timer and my function updateStatus get called every two minutes.

The problem is I want to use a thread to do the update because in case the timer is triggered again but my function called is not done, i will like to kill the thread and start a new one.

I understand I cannot use thread with EJB 3.1 so how should I do that? I don't really want to introduce JMS either.

Comment: "J2EE Glassfish" doesn't exist and makes no sense. Please be more specific about Glassfish version. Using EJB 3.0 suggests that you're using the 5 years old Glassfish v2 for Java EE 5. Is this true? Are you not actually using Glassfish 3.x for Java EE 6 with EJB 3.1? Your question history namely confirms that you're using Glassfish 3.1. If that were true, then the answer to this question would be extraordinary simple. For Glassfish v2 this isn't that simple.

Comment: Sorry for that. I use GlassFish 3.1 with EJB 3.0 and java EE 6

Comment: Why do you keep saying EJB 3.0? Glassfish 3.x (as every full fledged Java EE 6 container) ships with EJB 3.1. Did you have downgraded/replaced its EJB container by a 3.0 one somehow? Just to make sure that you're really using EJB 3.1 as it is in Glassfish 3.x in unmodified trim, because the answer which I'm about to post requires EJB 3.1.

Comment: I did not set up the project by myself but indeed the EJB 3.1 shipped with glassfish is not used in this project. We use a 3.0.

Comment: For what reasons exactly? Isn't that a misinterpretation? You seem to be pretty new to Java EE. You'll mis so much cool features like `@Schedule`. Your problem would be solved with only two annotations. Are you able to import `javax.ejb.Schedule`? If so, then you're definitely using EJB 3.1.

Comment: Indeed, the reasons is that the library containg the ejb 3.1 from gf is not included in our building script. Indeed I used the annotation to test but in this case I need to include the jar from gf in our build and unfortunately we dont want to use it.

Comment: Bummer. Good luck with the problem. I can only tell that you definitely shouldn't use `Timer`. It'll kill your app sooner or later.

Comment: Having saying that my problem is not to trigger an event every two minutes (this one works using a bean that implement timedobject. My problem is to be sure that my previous job is finished before I call a new one.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. You do **not** want to use `Timer` in a lifelong running Java EE app. Hint: start peeking around in Glassfish admin console.

Comment: Thanks for the answer tho, if the only solution is to used EJB 3.1 ? How would you implement it ? If it is really necessary, we might be able to add it in the built

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, I ll have a look

Comment: As said, Glassfish 3.x already ships with EJB 3.1 out the box. That's why I do by life not understand why you degraded it to EJB 3.0.

Comment: It is just we did not use include the jar file containing the EJB 3.1 from gf in the build script. Which mean we dont have access to the EJB 3.1 . Then As I just say if u tell me it is the only way to do it, I can add this jar to our building script.

Comment: Be lazy.  Create a jsp file that does what you want and call it with cron.

Comment: I updated the problem to work with EJB 3.1 so I can use the lock. Which is i think the right way to do it. @BalusC ? :)

Comment: Have you tried using an EJB timer and using an `@Asynchronous` annotation along with the `@Timeout` annotation on the method you want to run when the timer expires?

Answer (score 1):

You should simply use and EJB Timer for this.

When the job finishes, simply have the job reschedule itself. If you don't want the job to take more that some amount of time, then monitor the system time in the process, and when it goes to long, stop the job and reschedule it.

The other thing you need to manage is the fact that if the job is running when the server goes down, it will restart automatically when the server comes back up. You would be wise to have a startup process that scans the current jobs that exist in the Timer system, and if yours is not there, then you need to submit a new one. After that the job should take care of itself until your deploy (which erases existing Timer jobs).

The only other issue is that if the job is dependent upon some initialization code that runs on server startup, it is quite possible that the job will start BEFORE this happens when the server is firing up. So, may need to have to manage that start up race condition (or simply ensure that the job "Fails fast", and resubmits itself).